# Showing that $f(x,y)=(\lvert x\rvert -\lvert y\rvert)\log\left(2x^2+\lvert y\rvert\right)$ has no local extrema

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I have an exercise asking to find the local extrema of $$ f(x,y)=(\lvert x\rvert -\lvert y\rvert)\log\left(2x^2+\lvert y\rvert\right)$$if they exist... Wolfram Alpha tells me they don't, but I think I've spent too long trying to show it, so I'm wondering what I missed, resulting in a more time-consuming task. Below is my work:

$f$ is continuous on the whole plane except the origin.

For $x,y\ne0$$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x-y)\log\left(2x^2+y\right) &x,y>0 \\ (x+y)\log\left(2x^2-y\right) &x>0>y\\-(x+y)\log\left(2x^2+y\right) &x<0<y \\ -(x-y)\log\left(2x^2-y\right) &x,y<0\end{cases}$$hence $$f_x(x,y)=\begin{cases}\log\left(2x^2+y\right)+\dfrac{4x(x-y)}{2x^2+y} &x,y>0 \\ \log\left(2x^2-y\right)+\dfrac{4x(x+y)}{2x^2-y} &x>0>y \\ -\log\left(2x^2+y\right)-\dfrac{4x(x+y)}{2x^2+y} &x<0<y \\ -\log\left(2x^2-y\right)-\dfrac{4x(x-y)}{2x^2-y} &x,y<0 \end{cases} $$ and

$$f_y(x,y)=\begin{cases}-\log\left(2x^2+y\right)+\dfrac{x-y}{2x^2+y} &x,y>0 \\ \log\left(2x^2-y\right)-\dfrac{x+y}{2x^2-y} &x>0>y \\ -\log\left(2x^2+y\right)-\dfrac{x+y}{2x^2+y} &x<0<y \\ \log\left(2x^2-y\right)+\dfrac{x-y}{2x^2-y} &x,y<0 \end{cases}.$$ Setting both partial derivatives equal to $0$ I got $$\begin{cases}(x-y)(4x+1) &x,y>0 \\ (x-y)(4x+1) &x>0>y \\ (x+y)(4x-1) &x<0<y \\ (x-y)(4x-1) &x,y<0 \end{cases} \iff y=\pm x\ne0.$$ So for $x_0\ne0$ and small $h_1,h_2$ I examined \begin{align}\operatorname{sgn}\left\{f(x_o+h_1,\pm x_0+h_2)-f(x_0,\pm x_o)\right\}&:=\operatorname{sgn}(h_3\log(2x_0^2+|x_0|+h_4)) \\&= \operatorname{sgn}(h_3\log(2x_0^2+|x_0|)) \end{align}which obviously depends on how $h_3$ approaches $0$, so the $(x_0,\pm x_0)$ are saddle points.

EDIT: ok on second thought I forgot to show that $h_3$ doesn't depend on $h_1, h_2$ in a way that would make it approach $0$ only from the left/right, but let's pretend I did show it

Now I should study the behaviour around points $(x_0,0)$ and $(0,y_0)$ , and this is where I've been stuck. After a while I tried looking at things like $f(x_o,h)-f(x_0,0)$ but it didn't help... what am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you would solve this without some plotting assistance.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree, at this point I'm beginning to think it is a typo

Answer (score 1):

In the following I am assuming that $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Since $f(x,y) = f(|x|,|y|)$, we need only examine $x\ge 0, y \ge 0$.

For $x>0,y>0$ we have
$f_x(x,y) = {1 \over 2x^2+y} (4x (x-y) + (2x^2+y) \log(2x^2+y))$,
$f_y(x,y) = {1 \over 2x^2+y} ((x-y) - (2x^2+y) \log(2x^2+y))$.

Suppose $f_x(x,y) = f_y(x,y) = 0$, then the above gives
$x = - { 1 \over 4}$, hence $f$ has no stationary points in $x>0, y>0$.

The axes need more care, as $f$ is not differentiable there.

Now consider the $x$ axis, we have $f_x(x,0) = \log(2 x^2)+2$, which has
a
zero at $x^*={1 \over \sqrt{2}e }$. A little work shows that $x^*$ is a strict local $\min$ (of $x \mapsto f(x,0)$).

If we consider the $y \ge 0$ side of the graph, we have  $f_y(x^*,0) > 0$ (the one sided derivative) hence, with a little finesse, we can conclude that $f$ has a local $\min$ at $(x^*,0)$.

Now consider the $y$ axis, we have $f(0,y) = -y \log(y)$, which has a strict $\max$ at $y^* = {1 \over e}$. As above, by restricting to $x \ge 0$ and considering the one sided derivative, we see that
$f_x(0,y^*) = -1 <0$ from which we can conclude that $(0,y^*)$ is a strict
local $\max$.

To summarise, $f$ has strict local $\min$ at $(\pm {1 \over \sqrt{2} e}, 0)$ and
strict local $\max$ at $(0, \pm {1 \over e})$. There are no other
extrema.

Comment: Thank you! So was I _supposed_ to consider $\exp\circ \ f$? Should I always do that when the function is, naturally enough like in this case, a logarithm?

Comment: Well, there are no rules like that, but it is always worth a shot.

Comment: Sure but I mean in the context of an exam, where the time is limited. With my method I would have probably failed it because of this

Comment: Hard to say. Do you have a plotting calculator in the exam? I would look for symmetries (so we only need to consider the $x>0, y>0$ case and the axes), but there is no recipe, unfortunately.

Comment: Nope, no calculator admissible... well, I'll follow your advice and do more exercises, thank you

Comment: Good luck with your exam!

Comment: I realised I'm probably missing something here: when computing the partial derivatives of $\phi$ I get something different which I haven't been able to turn into your expressions. Could you help me please?

Comment: It is quite possible that I made a mistake ..

Comment: Ouch D: This seems almost helpless, especially if the other answer turns out to be correct

Comment: I made an egregious mistake, please unaccept my answer so I can delete it.

Comment: I need more sleep or caffeine :-(.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your time :)

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @Richard: I have changed my answer to something a little more reasonable. I will check again to see if I have errors, but you check yourself as well. I believe that $f$ has local $\max, \min$, but only on the axes. Because of the $|  \cdot |$, one needs to be a little careful with the extrema on the axes.

Comment: I am not sure from what level you are  approaching this, but it is not an entirely trivial problem because of the non differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$
f(x,y) = \left(|x|-|y|\right)\log(2x^2-|y|)
$$

has symmetries along the $x$ and $y$ axis because

$$
f(x,y) = f(\pm x, \pm y)
$$

Now considering the first quadrant or

$$
f(x,y) =(x-y)\log(2x^2-y)
$$

making the change of variable $u = 2x^2+y$ we have

$$
g(x,u) = (x+2x^2-u)\log u
$$

in this coordinate system the stationary points are given as the solutions for

$$
\nabla g(x,u) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
(1+4x)\log u & = & 0\\
x+2x^2-u - u\log u & = & 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

and solving we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & u & y \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{8 W\left(-\frac{e}{8}\right)} & -\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 W\left(-\frac{e}{8}\right)} \\
 -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{8 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e}{8}\right)} & -\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e}{8}\right)} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Here $W(\cdot)$ is the so called Lambert function. In numbers

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & u & y \\
 -1. & 1. & -1. \\
 -0.25 & 0.191569 & 0.0665694 \\
 -0.25 & 0.0860153 & -0.0389847 \\
 0.5 & 1. & 0.5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The feasible first quadrant solution gives

$$
x = \frac{1}{2}, u = 1, y = \frac{1}{2}
$$

The qualification for this stationary point is made with the contribution of the $g(x,u)$ hessian

$$
H_g = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 \log (u) & \frac{4 x+1}{u} \\
 \frac{4 x+1}{u} & -\frac{2 x^2+x-u}{z^2}-\frac{2}{u} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

At $(x,y) = (1/2,1/2)$ the hessian gives

$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 3 \\
 3 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

characterizing this point as a saddle point. Considering the four quadrants the surface takes the form shown below.

[image]

and we can observe the existence of local minima undetected by the traditional method.

[image]

The minima are located at

$$
\{x,y\} = \{\pm\frac{1}{e\sqrt2},0\}
$$

Comment: Nope, see the other answer

Comment: Yes you have reason concerning the points $(\pm \frac{1}{4},0)$ Those are saddle points but there are four local minima located at $\pm\frac{1}{4},\pm 0.0665694$

Comment: You might be right, but do you have any idea on how to find those minima analytically?

Comment: I added those conclusions to my answer.

Comment: Nice! Though those stationary points may well be all saddle points, am I wrong? After all Wolfram suggests so

Comment: Yes. Wolfram helps a lot. It serves as a magnifying glass, but the feeling is human.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm saying that I tend to think they're all saddle pointa

Comment: Not all. The points $\pm 0.25, \pm 0.0665694$ are local minima points. See note attached.

Comment: After the 3rd picture, you have a small typo. in that you have $x+y$ rather than $x-y$.

Comment: Actually, I think you have made a mistake with the plot, I believe $f$ has local extrema on the axes, but nowhere else.

Comment: Yes. My fault. All is due to this typo. Thanks. I will correct it ASAP.